# Android app that uses SQL Ce database?

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin, database-connection

Is possible to build an app for android that uses SQL CE database?
At the moment i have a .sdf database and no ideas on what programming languages i have to use to build the app i need. Is possible to do that using Xamarin framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SQL Server Compact only is available on Microsoft operating systems. For Android, you must use for example SQLite

Comment: There is no way to let the adroid device "convert" the .sdf database into SQLite and then work with it?

Comment: Nope, you must convert the sdf file on your desktop Pc to a sqlite database. My SQLite Toolbox can help you with that.